# проблема с getch() в игре

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

```
while (!m_endGame)
{
    m_action = getch();

     switch(m_action)
     {
        case ERR:
             break;

        case KEY_RIGHT:
            m_game->moveRight(1);
            break;

        case KEY_LEFT:
            m_game->moveLeft(1);
            break;

        case (int)' ':
            m_game->shoot();
            break;

        case (int)'z':
            m_game->changeCannonCollor();
            break;

        case 27:
            m_endGame = true;
        break;
    }
```

Вот фрагмент кода игры. Нужно чтобы пушка могла одновременно двигаться и стрелять но когда двигаю пушку например налево пушка останавливается потом стреляет и потом надо еще раз нажать стрелку для движения. помогите пож проверить сразу 2 нажатия клавиш

Comment: в какой системе программируете: в линуксе или виндоус? Движение стрелками?

Comment: программирую в linux е

Comment: движение стрелками?

Comment: да движение срелками

Comment: в таком случае приведите код, в котором обрабатываются первые два символа ввода, так как этот код не полный

Comment: у меня обрабатывается только один символ ... за обработку отвечает только код выше

Comment: раз так, то в этом случае этот код должен завершаться каждый раз, когда вы нажимаете стрелку, так как любая стрелка в линуксе кодируется тремя символами

Comment: этот код вообще не должен, по идее, обрабатывать стрелки...

Comment: можете привести пример ? этот момент не понимаю ... может нужно flush буфера сделать ?

Comment: KEY_RIGHT и KEY_LEFT макросы в ncurses для обработки нажатия стрелок

Comment: С  этим, если честно, не знаком... Но! Когда есть код типа: `a = getch()` при нажатии стрелки передается три символа, начиная с 27! Тоесь в `a` всегда будет 27, а остальные символы остаются в потоке ввода, до следующего запроса

Comment: а как можно очистить поток ?

Comment: вам его не очищать нужно, а брать эти символы. Вообщем этими макросами я никогда не пользовался, да они и не везде поддерживаются: http://www.linuxlib.ru/manpages/CURSES.3.shtml , но я пользовался чисто getch() для определения нажатия нужной клавиши. Щас набросаю в ответ

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, если `keypad()` включён, но тут всё в порядке и `getch()` возвращает один символ для стрелки, так что ты скорей всего не о том беспокоишься...

Comment: Возможно,  но, как я уже говорил, я не работал с этими макросами, да и тут не указано ничего про keypad()

Comment: keypad включен ))

Comment: @Artyom, не совсем понятно, какое именно поведение необходимо... опиши подробнее по шагам и/или сделай минимальный самодостаточный пример... Если это не пошаговая игра, то естественным было бы копать в сторону `timeout()`

Comment: у меня игра Space Invaders . И стрелки обрабатываются без проблем. но когда я держу нажатым например левую стрелку и пушка двигается на лево мне нужно чтобы в это время я смог одновременно и стрелять а здесь когда нажимаю пробел при движении пушка останавливается потом стреляет и потом еще раз нужно нажать стрелку для движения

Comment: @Artyom, подозреваю, что средствами ncurses, вообще говоря, это сделать не получится... как я понимаю, это эквивалентно задаче «отследить события нажатия и отпускания клавиши», но для этого unix-терминалы в принципе не предназначены. Можно, например, попробовать копнуть в сторону переключения в сырой режим для получения скан кодов (см. `ioctl(0, KDSKBMODE, K_RAW);` + `man 4 console_ioctl` + гугл), но это будет работать только в настоящем терминале...

Comment: Хм, интересно: попробовал написать прогу с keypad и макросами клавиш - ничего не вышло! Хоть keypad и включен, но при нажатии стрелки все равно посылается 3 символа вместо кода по макросу.